current_user from flask_login ambiguous behaviour
i am using flask_login for session management and flask_sqlalchemy as an ORM but current_user is behaving inappropriately, i am trying to update some data of current_user after login like this
from flask_login import current_user
current_user.name = "John"
db.session.commit()
sometimes it update the data in database but sometimes it is not, can someone help me to sort this out
here is my user table
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return db.session.get(User, int(id))


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)

after exploring about it i come to know that The Flask-Login current_user object is a LocalProxy object that acts as a proxy for the current user. It is not a database object, but rather a wrapper around the user object that provides additional functionality for authentication and authorization. Therefore, changing the current_user.name attribute will not update the user object in the database. If that then why it is changing it sometime

In order to understand exactly what happens, you need to take a look at LocalProxy and its implementation.
To avoid the ambiguous behavior, you can get the user object directly via _get_current_object and make your changes on it and then commit.
From the docs:

Return the current object this proxy is bound to. If the proxy is unbound, this raises a RuntimeError.
This should be used if you need to pass the object to something that doesn’t understand the proxy. It can also be useful for performance if you are accessing the object multiple times in a function, rather than going through the proxy multiple times.

